# How do you deploy a json script into the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc

I was trying to find a way to test out the blockcerts example [link](https://github.com/blockchain-certificates/blockcerts-playground.github.io), however I do not know how to deploy the script in the html page into the blockchain.

Any good tutorials for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't deploy javascript to blockchain.

But you can interact with blockchain by the means of web3, [here is a decent tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial)) to start with.
You can query blockchain for free, make transcations for transferring ETH or interacting with contracts for a gas fee. It's also possible to deploy your own contracts that are usually written in Solidity, [an online editor is available](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity).

When the contract has been deployed, the source code can be uploaded to the blockchain explorer, here is an example, [the Crypokitties source](https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code).

For experiments you should be using the [Ropsten test network](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/), it's almost the same as main one, but ETH in it has no value and you can get amount needed for test from an outlet.

Comment: thx for the answer!

Comment: but can I use remix for javascript?